# How can I access the primaryText from onChange method of SelectField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I access the primaryText from onChange method of SelectField? onChange provides only (event,index,value).

my code:

```
<SelectField 
    value={props.value} 
    onChange={this.handleChange}> 
       {props.options.map(opt => { 
             return ( 
                <MenuItem key={opt._id} value={opt._id} primaryText={opt.name} ></MenuItem> 
             ); 
          }
       )}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And also, please add code that you've tried.

Comment: `<SelectField
     value={props.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
         
      {props.options.map(opt => {

        return (
          <MenuItem
            key={opt._id}
            value={opt._id}
            primaryText={opt.name}
          ></MenuItem>
        );
      })}`

Comment: `this.handleChange=(event,index,value)=> {console.log(value)}`

Comment: paste it on your question so others can make it as reference and point where your mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way you’re rendering these MenuItems: using `props.options.map`.

This shows that your menu items are being rendered from an array in props.  You should use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the option with an `_id` matching the value.